# Field1 equals Field2 if Field1 is specific....

Tags: php, mysql

PHP/mysql
How can I do this? any help is really appreciated.
Database consist of 2 fields.
ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT
Field1 Var 6 nul
Field2 Var 6 nul
If I enter 1A2345 in field1, field2 should equal PO1A23
If I enter 2B1234 in field1, Field2 should equal Po2B12 and so on.
Field1 always changes, Field2 will have 24 items always the same.
I'm new to this, please be gentle.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what logic is applied. Can you explain a little more? Also, can you PLEASE edit your text "a little"?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're wanting to concatenate "PO" with the first 4 characters of Field1 and set Feild2 to that value.

To do this, you can simply set `Field2 = CONCAT('PO', SUBSTR(Field1, 1, 4))`.

An example of this would be as follows:

```
UPDATE table SET Field2 = CONCAT('PO', SUBSTR(Field1, 1, 4));
```

More information about [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [SUBSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I'm getting an error 'Syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in line 4'. Any ideas? shirejedi

Comment: That sounds like a PHP error.  Can you provide me with what you have on line 4?

Comment: UPDATE a1563161_data1 SET POLLID = CONCAT('PO', SUBSTR(PSCODE, 0, 4));

Comment: That's all you have on line 4? Is `PSCODE` a field on `a1563161_data1`? `0, 4` should actually be `1, 4`.  I had a typo but it's fixed now.

Comment: If this is in a PHP file, you'll need to use some database functions to pass that query to the database.  You can't just call it in the middle of your code if that's what you're doing.  Is there anyway you could provide a larger snippet of code in your original question?

Comment: function BeforeAdd($values,$message,$inline,$pageObject)
{

$values["PSCODE"] = strtoupper($values["PSCODE"]);
$values["POLLID"] = $values["PSCODE"];

UPDATE a1563161_data1 SET POLLID = CONCAT('PO', SUBSTR(PSCODE, 1, 4));
 
return true;

Comment: You'll probably need to read a bit about how to execute MySQL queries through PHP.  Here's a link to get you started: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#INSERT.2C_DELETE.2C_UPDATE_Prepared_Queries

Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful.